# Symfony - Cache key contains reserved characters

Tags: php, symfony, caching, symfony-3.4

I'm using Symfony 3.4.4, simple installation with FOSUser bundle. I have created simple form based on user entity:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm('Company\AdminBundle\Form\UserEditType', $user);
$editForm->handleRequest($request);
```

Form has only two inputs:

```
$builder
    ->add('name', TextType::class, ['label' => 'name and surname'])
    ->add('department', TextType::class, ['label' => 'department']);
```

When I submit form (I'm sending name, department and token), on `$editForm->handleRequest($request)` I'm getting exception:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Cache\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Cache key "myuser.email@address.com" contains reserved characters {}()/\@:" at /Sites/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Cache/CacheItem.php line 162 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Cache\Exception\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Cache key \"myuser.email@address.com\" contains reserved characters {}()/\@: at /Sites/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Cache/CacheItem.php:162)"} []

It only happens on prod env, on dev it works just fine.
I have no clue, no custom cache config, no additional cache bundles etc. OSX localhost apache with PHP 7.1.

Comment: Of course tried cache:clear already, doesn't help.

Comment: @goto yes, with env=prod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in slightly different place. In my `User` entity I had `email` property set up like this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
protected $email;
```

And there was a problem with `@Assert\Valid`, just don't know why (despite fact I don't know why there was just `Valid` used, not `Email()` etc., but doesn't matter right now).
Solution was simple, to get rid of this assert or just replace it with `@Assert\Email()`.

As I wrote, I have no clue why this caused such error. You can check and read issue here - https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26313

Answer (score 0):

You should look here: https://github.com/php-cache/issues/issues/49

Works with 0.4.3 of cache/cache-bundle. 0.4.4 broken. You can change cache-bundle version.

Comment: I have added `"cache/cache-bundle": "0.4.3"` with composer and updated AppKernel $bundles array with `new Cache\CacheBundle\CacheBundle(),`. 
Cleared production cache later, but no difference. Maybe I should do some additional config.yml stuff, but don't know exactly.